# Converting GMT date string to local Date object

Tags: java, date, calendar, timezone, simpledateformat

I'm trying to convert Date object(CST zone) to GMT String then back to Date object(CST).
 I've used the following code & it is working but wondering how it is converting GMT string to CST date with GMT Date formatter. 
My question is how can I get CST time back without using formatter with CST formatter?

```
Date inputdate = new Date();// My local time CST

System.out.println(inptdate);

SimpleDateFormat sdfgmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000'Z'");
sdfgmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

String gmtString = sdfgmt.format(inputdate );

System.out.println(gmtString);

Date outputDate  = sdfgmt.parse(gmtString);

System.out.println(outputDate);
```

**Output**

```
Fri Jan 18 22:52:47 CST 2013  
   2013-01-19T04:52:47.000Z  
   Fri Jan 18 22:52:47 CST 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

A java date has no concept of a timezone. A java date is simply a long that is stored. By printing the date you are converting that long to the timezone of your computer. If you are interested in storing a timezone, try Joda's DateTime class.

Comment: Wow.. you made my day Thanx Zylth, Joda time is impressive using DateTimeZone class for timezone changes. Thanx once again.